# YouTube AS3 Player API Error Code 0

Tags: flash, youtube-api

I've recently been getting lots of error code 0 using the AS3 Player API.  I decided to separate my app from the vanilla Player to make sure the error was not caused by my app.  For this I built the standalone AS3PlayerShim sample in Flex following the instructions from https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

The problem is reproducible in the build of the AS3PlayerShim.  Many videos are giving me error code 0, which is not documented in the Flash API Reference.  Below are example YouTube IDs that give an error code of 0 on playback.  There does seem to be some correlation of the newer "Vevo" branded music videos and getting the error code, but there does not seem to be a clear trend. Has anyone run into this issue before or know what the "0" error code means?

Here are some examples of YouTube IDs that give error code 0:

eDdI7GhZSQA
S09F5MejfBE
QUwxKWT6m7U
TAbnQZZ6QXc

Thanks.

Comment: please add the code you tried so people can help.

Answer (score 1):

this has been posted long ago but i experienced same issue recently.
The cause, atleast with mine is that i was using the loadVideoById() and was passing in the full youtube url
i only discovery this when i traced the url.