# YouTube API player does not play some videos

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, youtube-api

What does error code 0 mean in YouTube Flash API? It occurs when trying to play some videos with the API. Other error codes are explained in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference), but not error code 0.

How do I make the YouTube player play *all* videos, just like it does on [YouTube Player Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)?

FLA and SWF files: **https://s3.amazonaws.com/YouTubeAPIError0/YouTubeAPIError0.zip**

```
package {
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import fl.controls.ComboBox;
    import fl.controls.TextArea;

    public class YouTubeAS3 extends MovieClip {
        public var VidHolder:MovieClip;
        public var VidSelection:ComboBox;
        public var traceArea:TextArea;

        private var player:Object;
        private var loader:Loader;
        private var vidCollection:DataProvider;

        public function YouTubeAS3():void {
            Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
            Security.allowDomain("*");

            vidCollection = new DataProvider();
            vidCollection.addItem({data:"eDdI7GhZSQA", label:"Video 1"});
            vidCollection.addItem({data:"S09F5MejfBE", label:"Video 2"});
            vidCollection.addItem({data:"QUwxKWT6m7U", label:"Video 3"});
            vidCollection.addItem({data:"TAbnQZZ6QXc", label:"Video 4"});
            vidCollection.addItem({data:"QH2-TGUlwu4", label:"Errorless Video"});

            VidSelection.dataProvider = vidCollection;
            VidSelection.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, cueVideo);

            loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
        }

        private function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
            VidHolder.addChild(loader);
            loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
            loader.content.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
            loader.content.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
            loader.content.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
        }

        private function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
            traceArea.text += "player ready: " + Object(event).data + "\r";
            player = loader.content;
            player.setSize(480, 360);
            VidSelection.selectedIndex = 0;
            VidSelection.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        }
        private function cueVideo(event:Event):void {
            traceArea.text += "switch to: " + event.target.selectedItem.label + "\r";
            player.cueVideoById(event.target.selectedItem.data);
        }

        private function onPlayerError(event:Event):void {
            traceArea.text += "player error: " + Object(event).data + "\r";
        }

        private function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
            traceArea.text += "player state: " + Object(event).data + "\r";
        }

        private function onVideoPlaybackQualityChange(event:Event):void {
            traceArea.text += "video quality: " + Object(event).data + "\r";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that it was a bug in the Youtube player, where the Error wasn't properly initialized before dispatching the event. Unfortunately, I can't duplicate what you're seeing - the sample code you provided works just fine for me when I run it, with no errors at all.

Comment: @joshbuhler What makes your machine special? I was even connecting through U.S./Canada proxies multiple times and the error 0 persisted for the first 4 videos.

Comment: Is anyone else getting this bizarre error with the code above?

Comment: Nothing special that I know of. Just downloaded the code and ran it. You mention the proxies - are you running this outside the US? If so, have you tried it with videos that wouldn't be affected by what country you're in?

Comment: @joshbuhler So you say each of the first 4 videos play as they should for you with the sample code? Well, the fact is that I need all videos that play fine on YouTube site to be played trouble-free with the API. All of the first 4 videos play normally when I view them on the YouTube site (I'm outside U.S.), but not when I try to play them with the API. If I knew that at least visitors from U.S. would be able to view **all** videos, it'd give some relief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is:

> ["domain-level white/blacklisting is not exposed via the API currently."](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/6WRljEs8fQs)

[The accepted answer to the question "v3 api returns blocked content even with videoEmbedable = True" should also apply.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099980/v3-api-returns-blocked-content-even-with-videoembedable-true)

Answer (score 0):

I've had an error state of 0 - when the video times out.

If you look in the developer tools for whichever browser you're working with you should see a callout called 'videoplayback' which will have timed out. I have it timing out after 7.5 minutes, but that might be connection related.

Also, a 'timeout' error isn't covered in the currently documented error states.

Comment: But why it never plays some videos and produces error code 0 while always plays other videos without problems?

Comment: The list of options is currently:
HTML5 player vs. Flash player ( some videos are optimised for one and not the other )
Adverts - youtube injects ads into the streams, and I have no clue how to detect it.
Or you played a video once and it became cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question as [YouTube AS3 Player API Error Code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492097/youtube-as3-player-api-error-code-0) ... of course, that question doesn't have an answer, either (interesting, though, that the same 4 videos are used as examples of unplayable vids).

The only suggestion I'd have would be to look for a pattern in the data. For example, the v3 data API shows that all 4 videos you list which aren't playing are blocked in Germany, while the one you offer that does play has no such block. This would lead to the assumption that perhaps the error is related to a region block (note that a region block is different from the "embeddable" block, which is metadata that the uploader can set). The videos blocked in Germany are all done so because Vevo isn't allowed there, and they're all Vevo videos.

I'm not, of course, necessarily suggesting that the "unplayableness" is intentional, although it could be; I'm not aware of direct documentation that details what happens when the API (as opposed to the Youtube site, which uses different methods for playing the videos so you can't make any direct comparisons) tries to play a region blocked video. Perhaps @Dominic Orme is correct in that it's related to a timeout, a timeout caused by the region block (or by attempting to use a proxy to bypass the region block).

You can test this theory by finding other videos that would fit the pattern. For example, are all Vevo videos unplayable with your code? Are videos blocked in other countries also unplayable?

Comment: I was trying to add a sample code to that question before posting my own, but fruitless. Anyways, the 4 videos are not all Vevo videos, only the third is. In fact, Vevo videos are playable more often than not. I'm not in Germany, so I can't tell how much it's related to region blocking. One of the observed patterns would be that practically all Beatles videos are unplayable. In contrast, all the videos play fine on the YouTube site for me.

Comment: Yes ... my bad on the Vevo issue. I saw that the Taylor Swift vid was, and the others I only looked at through the data API so just made the assumption. However, the pattern still does show that the 4 videos you listed are all blocked in Germany (again, I wasn't suggesting you are in Germany, but perhaps there's something internally that's causing the error related to that). You say that Vevo videos generally work, and additional Beatles videos don't; could you offer some of those IDs to look at? Additionally, are there any videos that aren't music which don't play?

Comment: And to reiterate, in my experience something playing on the site generally bears little relation to the ability to play the video through the API as they work off of different methods for retrieval, playback, etc. Although you may also want to report on what happens when you try to embed these videos with an iframe, through the javascript API, etc. to see if you get different results.

Comment: Music videos I found so far: vU_sspkmDEc tCo7kAV4RHQ d8rd53WuojE 3QCZ_bv9aLc _H4TlDxXxVk

Comment: So it looks like all of those, too, have a region block on them (all for Germany, and one of them for the US as well). Another interesting thing I noticed is that when trying to access the embed SWF directly (i.e. http://www.youtube.com/embed/eDdI7GhZSQA) a message notes the video is "restricted from playback on certain sites." This happens whether or not there's actually a region block in place for the locale making the request. This tells me that whenever a region block is active, the internal API has to do some filtering and it's likely this which is causing (rightly or wrongly) the error.